# i need to write data to a file in c# but somehow it shows success but the file is empty

Tags: c#

Hello This is the code i am trying : 
If the file existes , append to that file else create a new one . I need to write data line by line

```
                    FileExists = File.Exists(NewFileName);
                    if (FileExists = false)
                    {
                        using (fs =new FileStream(NewFileName, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                            MessageBox.Show(Record);
                            sw.WriteLine(Record);
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (fd = new FileStream(NewFileName, FileMode.Append))
                        {
                            sw = new StreamWriter(fd);
                            MessageBox.Show(Record);
                            sw.WriteLine(Record,true);
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Seems like a but in FileExists check. Should be "i(f FileExists == false)"

Comment: @RobertHarvey This isn't a duplicate of that particular question (although I'm sure this one has been asked more than once).

Comment: MessageBox.Show is about the last thing you should do in the middle of a file write.

Comment: @phillip: That's probably for debugging purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey true but it could go before or after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your code never enters the `FileExists = false` branch: it is an assignment, not a comparison.

You can add an extra `=` to make it a comparison (i.e. make it `FileExists == false`) but the idiomatic way of checking the opposite of a condition is with the unary operator `!`.

Change the condition as follows to make it work:

```
if (!FileExists)
    ...
```

In addition, you forgot to close or flush your `StreamWriter`.

You can unify both branches by using the ternary operator, like this:

```
using (fs =new FileStream(NewFileName, FileExists ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create)) {
    sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    MessageBox.Show(Record);
    sw.WriteLine(Record);
    sw.Close(); // <<== Add this line
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! But No use checked that too

Comment: Yes i have tried showing the record and it does have a value and the file location is the same . have tried the append and write options for the file . i am not able to find where am i going wrong . It may be with the file mode or file access

Comment: @user2668901 You'd get an exception if there were a problem with file permissions. Check my last edit - you forgot to close the stream writer.